# É possível simplificar ainda mais esse código de pirâmide formada por asterisco?

Tags: c

Estou com um exercício simples onde preciso fazer uma piramide com asterisco usando estrutura de repetição.

A piramide tem 17 colunas e 9 linhas.

Meu programa exibe ela corretamente, É possível reduzir alguma linha ou algum `for`?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <conio.h>


main()


{
    int l,c,e;


    for (l = 1; l <= 10; l = l + 1)
    {
        for(e=1; e<=(l-1);e = e + 1)
        {
            printf(" ");
        }
        for (c = 1; c <= 10-l; c = c + 1)
        {
            printf("*");
        }

        for (c = 2; c <= 10-l; c = c + 1)
        {
            printf("*");
        }
    printf("\n");
    }
getch;
}
```

Comment: a propósito, evite ter variáveis com o nome `l` - é um símbolo dificil de distinguir visualmente de  `1` e torna a leitura do seu código mais difícil. (No caso da fonte aqui to stackoverflow, o símbolo fica praticamente idêntico a `1` - mas mesmo com outra fontes é bem ruim)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Uma alternativa:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {
    int l, c;
    for (l=1; l<10; l++) {
        for(c=0; c<=7+l; c++)
            printf(c<9-l?" ":"*");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Veja funcionando no **[IDEONE](http://ideone.com/30UqUo)**.

Answer (score 11):

Dá sim:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    for (int x = 9; x > 0; x--) {
        for(int y = 9 - x; y > 0; y--) printf(" ");
        for (int y = 1; y <= x * 2 - 1; y++) printf("*");
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/9PLHI2). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/hhoqgsga-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Pyramid.c).

Além de eliminar um dos laços que só repetia o que o outro fazia, dei uma organizada e modernizada no código. Preferi inverter a contagem do laço e usar nome de variável mais fácil de ler.

Não use `conio.h`. Está obsoleto.

Mas se quiser fazer mais simples ainda e usar laço, pode fazer isto:

```
int main(void) {
    for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++) {
        printf("*****************\n");
        printf(" ***************\n");
        printf("  *************\n");
        printf("   ***********\n");
        printf("    *********\n");
        printf("     *******\n");
        printf("      *****\n");
        printf("       ***\n");
        printf("        *\n");
    }
}
```

Quanto menos desvios e variáveis e mudanças de estado, mais simples, mesmo que não seja o mais curto.

Se ainda deseja o mais curto tem alguns truques possíveis. Uma opção:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void) { for (int x = 9; x > 0; x--) printf("%.*s%.*s\n", 9 - x, "         ", x * 2 - 1, "*****************"); }
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/ktICq3). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/prjubgao-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Algorithm/Pyramid2.c).

Comment: Curti demais essa última opção, parece que é brincadeira mas certa vez ouvi que: para fazer algo eficiente as vezes precisamos "pensar como um preguiçoso". Assim os 3 primeiros algoritmos resolvem o problema de maneira eficaz mas o último foi o mais eficiente. 

Comment: @iTSangar eu apresentaria este pra quem pediu o exercício largar mão de ser besta :) Até entendo o objetivo, mas requisitos artificias merecem soluções criativas pra burlá-los. O cara tem que aprender fazer o requisito pra forçar o laço de verdade e não artificialmente. Eu vivia fazendo isto com professor meu que mandou "criar funções que só tivessem uma responsabilidade", não era a intenção dele, mas eu entreguei praticamente um Assembly, tinha coisas do tipo `Soma(x,y){ return x+y}`