# Algorítimo que faz arvore de asteriscos *

Tags: c#, algoritmo, lógica

Estou com um problema em uma atividade, a atividade seria fazer uma árvore de asteriscos do tipo:

```
   *
  ***
 *****
```

porém com meu código

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 5 ; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");

            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

o resultado é algo parecido com isso

```
*
**
***
****
*****
```

alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Imprima a quantidade adequada de espaços antes de imprimir o '*'.

Comment: Veja isto: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136861/101

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consegui fazer de um jeito que ficou melhor, a sua resposta só funcionava com o valor 3.
nesse código, posso colocar qualquer valor no X que irá funcionar

```
var x = 10;

        for (int i = 0; i <= x; i++)
        {
            for (int j = x; j > i; j--)
            {
                Console.Write(" ");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j <= i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            {
                Console.Write("*");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Fiz um mais simples ainda, que só usa quatro linhas de código.

```
const int linhas = 5;

for(int i = 0; i <= linhas*2; i++)
    if(i % 2 != 0)
        Console.WriteLine(new string(' ', (linhas*2 - i) /2 ) + new string('*', i));
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fqDfKp).</sup>